# QSize candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++, qt4, qt4.7

i have this code

```
QSize size;
size.setHeight(3);
size.setWidth(3);
QWidget window;
QCheckBox* botonera = new QCheckBox("hola",&window);
botonera->baseSize(size);
```

Why is the botonera->baseSize(size) telling me it has to be a different kind of type? The error tells me that the candidate is waiting no argumets but i have provided one.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`QWidget::baseSize()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#baseSize-prop) is a "getter" method. It returns the base size. If you want to set the base size, use the corresponing "setter" method: `setBaseSize(const QSize&)`.